# VS2012 like multiple web.config transformations in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, web-config-transform

Is it possible to use the VS2012 [profile specific web.config transformations](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2012/08/20/profile-specific-web-config-transforms-and-transform-preview.aspx) within a VS2010 project?

Utilizing build configurations is getting out of had with the project I am currently working on. Thus I have been looking at alternatives such as [Douglas Rathbone's "Multiple Tiers" approach](http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/using-custom-webconfig-0).

I am aware that with the launch of VS2012 this is a solved problem, however I don't have the opertunity to upgrade to VS2012 yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

If you install the `Windows Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2010 SP1)` from this Microsoft link here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/jj161045 it will give you the updated Web Deploy functionality that was included with 2012.

Then, you can create a `Web.<profile_name>.config` file in your project and it will use that file, after applying any changes from a Configuration-named config file if it exists, as outlined in this post: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TinyHappyFeatures3PublishingImprovementsChainedConfigTransformsAndDeployingASPNETAppsFromTheCommandLine.aspx

Comment: Thanks, when I was looking this wasn't available; in the end I came up with a not-dissimilar solution using MSBuild tasks - https://github.com/RichardSlater/MultipleWebConfigTransforms